# White page Webform email: Send as html

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

I am using:

- Webform 7.x-3.21
- HTML Mail 7.x-2.65

If i set the following option in the backoffice of a specific webform (send e-mail as HTML):
[image: option webform email backoffice]

I get the a white page when submitting the form and no e-mail is send.
No white page appears if the option is not checked.

I didn't get any errors in the logging, so i started to dig in the code and saw the process stopped @file webform.module @line 2968 in the _webform_filter_values function. The moment we render the display_element.

```
$replacements['email'][$format]['%email[' . $form_key . ']'] = render($display_element);
```

The only thing i can think of is the memory limit being to low. ( can't test it now). Anyone else had this problem ? Thx!

Comment: can you access your web server's error log for this site?  This is going to be the most direct way to see what's going on.

Comment: Not today, but i can check this toworrow. What error's should i look for? If get a php error, it should be logged in the drupla dblog ?

Comment: What I like to do is find the log and "tail -f error_log",  then I go do what I was trying to do.  It should give you the full picture of errors in real time.   you've got a lot going on when you're sending an email like that.  could be the webform module, or the actual routing of email, or just a simple out of memory thing.

Comment: THX! I managed to find the error in these log. It was caused by a custom hook_webform_element function wich called an undefined function webform_filter_xss instead of _webform_filter_xss.